# Brightening an image using styles or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to brighten an image on my webpage on mouseover using css or javascript.
Ive seen some examples using opacity and filters in styles but they dont seem to work for me.

Thanks in advance

CP

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify in a more concrete manner what you've tried already.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**

A pure CSS solution would be to use [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

```
img:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.5);
}
```

Here we add 50% brightness to all images on hover.

---

Why not? You can always set the background of the parent container to #fff (white) and then lower the opacity of the image.

HTML:

```
<div class="white">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.white { background: #fff; }
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Another solution is to use a JavaScript library, such as [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/lighten/).

Comment: I realise CSS < Photoshop, but that won't brighten the image as much as wash it out... Of course, it could be just what CP is after though. :)

Comment: Added another suggestion as well, the use of Pixastic: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/lighten/

Comment: I get the error
filter is not a known css property name
opacity is not a known css property name

Comment: I'm too slow. You may get that error, as I dont think it is valid CSS. I cannot remember why. But if it works, it works. Who cares if it validates.

Comment: it would be if it worked.  when i hover over the image nothing seems to happen

Comment: it won't work in all browsers. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: ie 6 i can get the style to brighten but not on mouseover see post below

Comment: IE6 does not support the :hover psudeo class on other elements than anchors. You can get around this by turning the image to an anchor or use JavaScript to add/remove class as the user hover over the image.

Comment: thanks mickel I used the javascript method
Thanks to all who replied

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS sprites. Create 2 versions of the image: one normal, one bright and combine them into 1 image using Photoshop or whatever you use.

There's a good explanation of what CSS sprites are [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Of course, this may not be something you could use on your site. For example, it's probably not something you'd want to use on large images (they'd double in size). You also couldn't do it this way if the images you want to brighten come from outside sources or are uploaded by users for example. It would work well for things like navigation bar images and other UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something liek:

```
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
```

As far as I know, this is the only way to accomplish it in CSS. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes, I can get it to brighten the image but its not working on mouseover so i must be doing something wrong!

img class = "mouseover"

        .mouseover img 
            {
                opacity: 0.3; 
                filter: alpha(opacity=30); 
            }

Comment: In this case, change that to: img.mouseover:hover { etc. }

Comment: the class needs to come immediately after the tag. then the selector, immediately after that. so: tag.class:selector { etc. }

Comment: Thanks Ryan, nearly there the hover bit doesnt work tho

       .img.mouseover
            {
                filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
                opacity: 1.0; 
            }

        .img.mouseover:hover
            {
                filter: alpha(opacity=30); 
                opacity: 0.3; 
            }