# Set image or div as background

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, background

is it possible that setting fullsize background using img attribute?
there is no any problem when I use like this.

```
    <ion-content padding="true" class="loginView">
 <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="girisimage">
            <h1 ng-click="toKategoriler()" class="cilbil">BUL</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-wrapper">
           <img ng-src="img/kbldlogo.jpg" />
      </div>

</div>

    </ion-content>

.loginView{ 
  background: url('../img/landing.jpg');
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  text-align:-webkit-center;
}
```

but I need to change image's brightness.If I change it's brightness within loginView, it will effect all object withing this content as you know.
I don't know if there is a way or not to change only the image's brightness by this way.

I am thinking that there is not any way.that's why I am asking How can I set `<img src="">` or `<div ></div>` as background just like the way above?

Comment: it's difficult to increase brightness with CSS, if I understand correctly. It is easier to darken an image (using an overlay) but to brighten, it would be easier to edit the image with Photoshop, or Pixlr and then replace the image.

Comment: you are right, but the images may update dynamicly :/ maybe there is any way with javascript ?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644399/brightening-an-image-using-styles-or-javascript

Comment: actualy I am using these tricks [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) the problem is setting brightness only the image, not all content.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
body{
 background-image: url('../img/landing.jpg');
}
```

Comment: if I do like this,all object will be effected.I need to do this with div or img ..